# What Happens if you Stop SpServiceInstance

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search

Windows Infrastructure team last night restarted our Lower end servers. Post re-boot we have now encountered error in 2 app server who is hosting Query and Index processing services of Search Application.

Troubleshooting Steps:

- restarted Windows Search service 15 service
- rebooted server

that resulted in No success. Weird thing is it hasn't effected search at all, Contents are being crawled fine and search is working as expected.

In CA-->Manage Services in Server, i see Error Stopping status.

Aside from the above troubleshooting steps I have applied community seems to advise using

Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity

And finally:

Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity

If I would go ahead and do this, but i want to know what exactly would this cmdlet do behind the  pictures.

Will my index would be wiped out?
Will this malfunction my search services?

Answer (score 3):

```
Stop-SPServiceInstance
```

This cmdlet will Stops the service instance for a service on the specified server or for the farm.

Use the Start-SPServiceInstance cmdlet to start the service instance for a service on a specific server or on the farm.

**This will not wipe index**

Comment: My Service is stuck in Error Stopping Status, but my search is working as expected. Shoudl i first stop it then start ?

Comment: Yes there is no harm executing Stop even if the service is in stopped state.

Comment: Is their a technet document for the reference.

Comment: Here is the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704549(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Didnt work it gave following error"Invalid search service unprovisioning: application 'SearchServiceApp' still has a ready component 'in search service instance' on server "

Comment: @allegrooctopus I'm facing that same error now. Did you manage to work around it?

Comment: We involved MSFT Premiere Support for this case, but no solution from them either, at the mean time we had SQL reboot Scheduled as part of monthly maintenance plan. After SQl was rebooted, it started working again. Unfortunately we couldn't find the root cause, but rebooting sql fixed our issue.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping and Starting the services application on a specific services will not hurt the Search services applications.

Only draw back is, if any crawl is running then it will wait for services come online but if it take too much time( i can say 1 hour) then crawl will timed out, then it will cause issue and as per my experience(1 instance in last 5 years) where we have to rebuild the index.

So stop the crawl then do this.

I read your comment about invalid search service.....In this case you have to run this command:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources
```

Read this for more info.http://spmasters.blogspot.com/2011/10/troubleshooting-search-service-stuck-in.html

http://blog.jaey.ca/post/Get-out-of-Stopping-Status-from-SharePoint-Search2.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your responce Waqas, But will Psconfig in any way update my database. i am always doubtful about using psconfig commands?

Comment: What are the consequences of using the following command.

Comment: Also What Security will be enforced on files, folders and registry keys due to psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources

Comment: it will not update the databases, This command is helpful in order to make sure that all the sharepoint resources are secure & user accounts have correct access previleges.

Comment: Thank you i will run that command first then stop crawl and stop the service using powershell command and finally start again.

Comment: stop the crawl before then command and than stop/start services.